# Python maketrans function

Tags: python, string

Rencently, I have read definition about maketrans() as: The maketrans() method returns a mapping table that can be used with the translate() method to replace specified characters.

```
txt = "Hello Sam!"
mytable = txt.maketrans("S", "P")
print(txt.translate(mytable))
```

What mapping table is? And how do parameters of it work?
I have just learned python for 3 weeks and am completely new to programming.
Thank you.

Comment: What is unclear in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans)? If you're new to programming and Python, I recommend that you always start by reading it.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille yes, I have read the documentation and I just don't understand it

Comment: " I just don't understand it " - we won't rewrite a complete documentation for this method hoping that you will understand it better. You need too be much more specific about what exactly you don't understand.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I am really sorry for that, thanks for saying me this, I'll try to say it clearer next time

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*What mapping table is?*

When faced with such question, you might use `type` to determine class of object, like so:

```
txt = "Hello Sam!"
mytable = txt.maketrans("S", "P")
print(type(mytable))
```

output

```
<class 'dict'>
```

It is `dict`, that is dictionary (*associative array* if you wish to use langauge-agnostic terminology).

Answer (score 0):

The `translate` method replaces characters in a string.
Let's check for example the use case found here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-maketrans-translate-functions/

They want to turn the string

```
weeksyourweeks
```

to

```
geeksforgeeks
```

To turn the first string into the second string, we need to replace

- w by g
- y by f
- we need to drop u

We can archive this using the `translate` method of a string.
To apply this method we need a *translation table* that contains the mappings in the list above.
The `maketrans` method builds that table.

The first argument to `maketrans` are the characters that need to be replaced. In our case that is w and y (`"wy"`).
These characters need to be replaced by g and f respectively (`"gf"`).
The last argument gives the characters that need to be dropped.
In our case that is u (`"u"`).

Let's see what maketrans returns when we use these arguments:

```
>>> str = "weeksyourweeks"
>>> str.maketrans("wy", "gf", "u")
{119: 103, 121: 102, 117: None}
```

If you look up what these ints represent in [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), the returned dictionary states this:

```
{
    'w': 'g',
    'y': 'f',
    'u': None
}
```

When we call `translate` it will translate w to g, y to f and delete u (indicated by None).

```
>>> str.translate({119: 103, 121: 102, 117: None})
'geeksforgeeks'
```